# Avoid inflating layout manually by passing layout id

Tags: android, fragment

I'm new to Kotlin, and this syntax in [this project](https://github.com/Enes-Kayiklik/Comic-Reader) is not familiar to me:

```java
@AndroidEntryPoint
class CommentsFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_comments) {
```

It seems that by passing layout to the constructor, manual inflating/`findViewById` can be avoided, and views can be referenced by using the `id` in xml.

What is this new syntax/feature called?

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.1.0

Was added in 1.1.0 it's just optional and still seems like it calls the code you would normally call yourself.

"Fragment LayoutId constructor" is the name they use there.